# Hands when playing Omaha

Tags: rules, reading-hands, omaha

When playing Omaha If the community cards have 3 nines come up and I hold the 4th nine can I claim four of a kind?

Answer (score 9):

Yes.  You must use exactly two cards from your hand to make your best 5-card poker hand, so if there were three 9's on the board your best hand would use the 9 and the highest ranked other card from your hand.  For example, if you held KQ97 and the board were 999AJ, your best hand would use the 9 and K, for a best hand of 9999K. Of course, in this case the kicker is meaningless, since no other player can also have quad 9's.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **yes**. 
And although you didnt ask here is some side info : 
Kickers do not matter with Quads in Omaha.
When you hold quads you can only loose to a straight / royal flush or higher quads. 
I think the odds of losing with Quads is around 1 in 56,000